# Change color text script

Tags: html, text, colors

I've been looking for a button that pops up a grade with all colors and outputs the text to one determinate area but could't find.

Is there any script know for this? I want to apply it to a comment section I'm doing.

Comment: Can you give an example? Maybe what you've tried so far as well?

Comment: http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/ ?

Comment: You definitely aren't going to get one in plain html... what framework(s) are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an html editor with colorPicker:
http://jquery-plugins.net/freshereditor-jquery-rich-text-editor

10 Color Picker Plugins | jQuery4u
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-color-pickers-plugin/

10 Useful Free jQuery Color Picker Plugin
http://www.webdesigntunes.com/freebies/jquery-color-picker-plugins/

http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/